# Querying Distinct Events from Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

Right now I have a very simple query that pulls up entries that have a string and a specific date range.

```
   EventQuery eQuery = new EventQuery(calendarInfo.Uri.ToString());

   eQuery.Query = "Tennis";
   eQuery.StartDate = startDate;
   eQuery.EndDate = endDate;

   EventFeed myResultsFeed = _service.Query(eQuery);
```

After querying, myResultsFeed will contain an atomEntryCollection.  Each atomEntry has a Title.  The way I have it set up, there could be multiple entries with the same title.

I would like my Query to be able to select UNIQUE titles.  Is this possible?

[Link to the API Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html)

I hypothesized that I could use a WHERE object

```
Where x = new Where();
x.yadayada();
```

but it can't be passed to _service.Query()

I'm also exploring the .extraparameters object. is it possible to do something like this?

```
eQuery.ExtraParameters = "distinct";
```

Looking into the "Partial Response" feature..

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html#PartialResponse

it looks pretty promising..

Comment: A suggestion: have you tried asking around the Google Apps API forums? You might get a definite answer over there: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis?hl=en.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think what you're trying to do is possible using the Google Data API.
However, extenting upon @Fueled answer, you could do something like this if you need a collection of AtomEntry's.

```
// Custom comparer for the AtomEntry class
class AtomEntryComparer : IEqualityComparer<AtomEntry>
{
    // EventEntry are equal if their titles are equal.
    public bool Equals(AtomEntry x, AtomEntry y)
    {
        // adjust as needed
        return x.Title.Text.Equals(y.Title.Text);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(AtomEntry entry)
    {
        // adjust as needed
        return entry.Title.Text.GetHashCode();
    }
}

EventFeed eventFeed = service.Query(query)

var entries = eventFeed.Entries.Distinct(new AtomEntryComparer());
```

Comment: Yeah, I have a lot of data to sort through.  It looks like the "I don't think" part of your answer is going to be the closest we will get..

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the solution you were looking for, but since you have in hand an `AtomEntryCollection` (which down the line implements `IEnumerable<T>`), you could use LINQ to retrieve the distinct titles, like so:

```
EventFeed feed = service.Query(query);

var uniqueEntries =
    (from e in feed.Entries
    select e.Title.Text).Distinct();
```

And then loop over them with a simple `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in uniqueEntries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

But then you have only a collection of `string` representing the Event titles, and not a collection of `AtomEntry`. I guess you could link them together in a Dictionary.
Not optimal, but should work.

Comment: alas, in my case I have a LOT of CalendarEntries.  I didn't want to have to pull them all down.